# Ionic does not show json data on android emulator or devapp

Tags: android, asp.net-core-webapi, ionic4, ionic-devapp

On `localhost:8100` with `ionic serve` command, app is calling `json` data via web `api` (asp.net core backend that enabled CORS with origins http://localhost:8100)  which is working fine.
Now, I tested with both devapp on galaxy 9 and `android` emulator (`ionic`cordova`emulate android`). Both shows the app's layout, but it does not fetch json data.

Does anyone know what the problem is or how to debug it on `devapp`/`android` `emulator` like I can do it on browser's console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chrome://inspect/#devices` to debug Android devices/emulators and check below:

1. See if there is any error in console logs (maybe JavaScript is breaking due to which this is happening)
2. Check if API is getting called and getting response.

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) official information for how to use chrome inspect devices.

Comment: okay thanks. I tried what you said and added more stuff above. Any idea what is causing the issue please.

Comment: @bbusdriver I have answered to your original question of how to debug. For this new requirement please create separate question. If my answer is helpful then please give upvote and accept it.

Comment: Created another one Vic.

Comment: @bbusdriver Please read my comment again. CREATE SEPARATE NEW QUESTION. Don't edit this. Keep it original. I have rolled back it original. Request you to create new question. thanks

Comment: oops sorry forgot to link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238715/ionic-does-not-fetch-rest-data-on-android-emulator-or-devapp)